# Search with custom routing in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

According to elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html#_searching_with_custom_routing), the search request below should only be executed on shards containing user1 routing values.

Query:

```
GET my-index-000001/_search?routing=user1
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "document"
    }
  }
}
```

However, I get the following result for the query above:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.11859183,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my-index-000001",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.11859183,
        "_routing": "user1",
        "_source": {
          "title": "This is a document"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my-index-000001",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.10943023,
        "_routing": "user1",
        "_source": {
          "title": "This is another new document"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my-index-000001",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.10158265,
        "_routing": "user2",
        "_source": {
          "title": "This is a document in user2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my-index-000001",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.0947853,
        "_routing": "user2",
        "_source": {
          "title": "This is a another document in user2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Despite specifying the routing parameter in the search query to be user1, why does it retrieve documents with routing value of user2 as well?

Is it because both user1 and user2 can reside on the same shard, so this query matches and retrieve all the documents from the same (and only single) shard?

I expected to get hits of documents containing routing values as user1 but got hits of documents with value of user2 as well

Answer (score 0):

When specifying a routing value, only one shard will be searched as can be seen in the response.

```
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
```

When specifying `routing=user1` you cannot expect to only get documents with `user1` values, otherwise that would mean that you have as many primary shards as number of distinct user values, which only makes sense if the number of users is low (<10).

The routing value is not a way to filter data in your search query, for that you need to use a `term` filter, it's only a way to specify the specific shard to search because you know the documents you need to search will be on that shard as they've all been indexed with the same routing value.

Finally, if your index has a single primary shard, then using the routing value doesn't bring anything since all the data will be indexed on that single and only shard anyway.

**UPDATE:**

In response to your comment below:

> However, the number of primary shards is equal to the number of distinct user values i.e 2. Hence, why are both docs with different routing values placed on the same shard?

The fact that you're using two different routing values doesn't mean that they will end up in two different shards. The routing value is hashed using the [murmur3 hashing function](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/routing/Murmur3HashFunction.java#L35) (x86, 32 bit) and then used in the following formula to deduce the shard ID:

```
shard_num = (hash(_routing) % num_routing_shards) / routing_factor
where routing_factor = num_routing_shards / num_primary_shards
```

In your case `routing_factor` is 1 (i.e. 2 routing shards / 2 primary shards), so the shard ID is basically the hash of the _routing value mod 2.

Using your routing values, we get the following shard IDs (you can experiment murmur3 [here](http://murmurhash.shorelabs.com/)):

```
murmur3("user1") % 2 = 3305849917 % 2 = shard 1
murmur3("user2") % 2 = 4180509323 % 2 = shard 1
```

You can test with a document having `user3` as routing value and you'll see it would land on another shard:

```
murmur3("user3") % 2 = 2032664284 % 2 = shard 0
```

Comment: Does the shard response contain the total number of shards in the index or the total number of shards searched across for the given query? I re-created the example above with 2 shards & get a value of 2 in the shard response for the same search query.

Comment: The shard response contains the total number of shards that were visited. When specifying a "routing" value, it can only be 1. It's perfectly possible, though, that even with two shards, both user1 and user2 documents land on the same shard.

Comment: Can you please explain why 2 shards were visited when a "routing" value was specified: [link](https://ibb.co/pbPC9zD)

Comment: I tried reproducing your example and only one shard was visited, which makes sense. Maybe provide a full recreation example so we can see what's going on

Comment: Here's the complete example with steps executed in sequential order: [link](https://ibb.co/8K1jF1N)

Comment: Ok I understand now, if you want your query to use routing you need to specify it [adequately](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.7/mapping-routing-field.html#_searching_with_custom_routing) like you do at indexing time, basically like this `GET my-index-0001/_search?routing=user1` and not with a `terms` query on the `_routing` field.

Comment: Well, that's correct. The response of `GET my-index-0001/_search?routing=user1` indicates that 1 shard was visited: [link](https://ibb.co/XjSGsG3).  However, the number of primary shards is equal to the number of distinct user values i.e 2. Hence, why are both docs with different routing values placed on the same shard?

Comment: Can you show the results you get from `GET my-index-0001/_settings?include_defaults`  and I will answer that comment directly in my answer because that's important

Comment: Here: [link](https://gist.github.com/bm2515/60bc202225262b79742fd9d40987889b)

Comment: Yes, Indeed! Thank you very much, Val. I summarized the differences between the queries we discussed here: [link](https://gist.github.com/bm2515/eba1f9a0ab53a2468079ad5e99f83a38)

Comment: Yes, that's pretty correct!